# How to continue Javascript variable onto 2nd line when over 80 characters

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm trying to take this:

```
payrate = Number(document.getElementById("payrate").value) * 8 * travelers;
```

and make it into something like this:

```
payrate = Number(document.getElementById("payrate").value) * 8 *
payrate += travelers;
```

However I know this is wrong. My only experinece with this was when I was just injecting in a string, not an actual variable that can change based off of what the user inputs. How do I get what I'm defining as my variable to move on to a second line?

Comment: You can break the expression at any whitespace character. (Also lots of other places.)

Comment: VS Code + Prettier

Answer (score 1):

It's good to be alert in JavaScript to potential weird effects of newlines, but within an expression you're safe.  There are many places in your expression where line breaks can be introduced; for example:

```
payrate = 
  Number(document.getElementById("payrate").value) *
  8 * 
  travelers;
```

If you're interested in concise code, the unary `+` operator is equivalent to the `Number()` function:

```
payrate = 
  +document.getElementById("payrate").value *
  8 * 
  travelers;
```

Comment: I'm going to have to ask my instructor on this actually. We have to make sure there are no errors through JSLint, but if I use your method or go over 80 characters, I get an error. I do appreciate what you mentioned because I actually was not aware of that.

Comment: @mightymorphinParkRanger "I get an error" — what error exactly? If you were to post that information, you could get much more useful help. And there's absolutely nothing magical about 80 characters. JSLint is **extremely** opinionated, based on literally one person's ideas about code "quality".

Comment: The errors I typically get are "Undeclared" and it lists my variable. If it's not that, it's that my code is more than 80 characters for a line.

I think then this is mostly geared toward my instructor then. They specifically want us to have our code have 0 errors through JSLint. I have my class later today but I will post an answer to it once I find out how he wants us to do it.

Comment: The "Undeclared" error means that `payrate` or `travelers` are not declared with `let` or `var`; it has absolutely nothing to do with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

why don't let prettier worry about that, https://prettier.io/

Answer (score 0):

So I asked my instructor and here's what he showed me:

```
      function byID(element) {
    return document.getElementById(element);
  }
```

and then we replaced that with the whole document.getElementbyID(element);. We also just made the variable shorter or just substituted multiple variables combined into one. So I guess nothing fancy in the end.